# Swift - Dynamically added action doesn't fire

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function which should "toggle" a bar button item by changing between 2 images.

```
class Buttons {
    func ToggleBarButton(button : UIBarButtonItem, name : String, location : BarButtonLocation, isEnabled : Bool, viewController : UIViewController) {
        var iconName = name
        if (!isEnabled) {
            iconName += "EnabledIcon"
        } else {
            iconName += "DisabledIcon"
        }

        let newIcon = UIImage(named: iconName)
        let newButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: newIcon, style: .Plain, target: self, action: button.action);

        switch location {
        case BarButtonLocation.Left:
            viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newButton;
            viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor();
        case BarButtonLocation.SecondLeft:
            viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?[1] = newButton
            viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?[1].tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        default:
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a view controller class, in which there is the action of the bar button item.

```
class GradesViewController: UIViewController {
    var isFilterEnabled = false
    var isViewEnabled = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func filterButton_Pressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        Buttons().ToggleBarButton(sender, name : "Filter", location: BarButtonLocation.Left, isEnabled: isFilterEnabled, viewController: self);
        isFilterEnabled = !isFilterEnabled;
    }

    @IBAction func viewButton_Pressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        Buttons().ToggleBarButton(sender, name : "View", location: BarButtonLocation.SecondLeft, isEnabled: isViewEnabled, viewController: self);
        isViewEnabled = !isViewEnabled;
    }
}
```

On first press it successfully changes the image to the enabled form, but on second press it doesn't do anything (press event doesn't even fire). I checked, and `button.action` is correctly identified as `"filterButton_Pressed:"`. What's the problem, or is there an easier way to do this? Thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: `Buttons().ToggleBarButton(...)` calls `ToggleBarButton` on a brand-new `Buttons` instance. This does not seem right.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I just realized the problem was that I copied the code from the view controller to the button class, and didn't change `target: self` to `target: viewController`. Now it works fine. But now I'm interested in that new button instance... How should it be written correctly?

Comment: Since `ToggleBarButton` function in `Button` does not use instance variables, you should make it `static` (or `class`, it's the same thing) and call it by referencing class name, rather than making a new instance.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's a good point, thanks. I'm just getting used to swift... Well, I should really learn it properly instead of trying to find out with knowledge of C# :)

Comment: Figuring it out with the knowledge of C# is a valid strategy - it seems to be working fine for me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the problem was that I copied the code from the view controller to the button class, and didn't change `target: self` to `target: viewController`. But thanks for all the answers anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Put the break statement after each case and try.
And also remove the semi colons.

Comment: Of course, thanks, but this wasn't the problem.  (I wonder why it worked though. It should've toggled the other button too...)

Comment: @Geiszla breaks are optional in switch statements. Semi colons are optional too.